# How Playframework Scala Facebook or other social media authorization

Tags: facebook, scala, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to make a prototype web service. I'm using Play framework 2.3.8, Scala 2.11. I would like to implement user sign-in by using Facebook or any other social media service. I'm trying to find an online tutorial or any blog which explains how to do this. All I find is Play and Java related. Nothing about Scala. Could you please share some link how where to read about about it?

Comment: It is unclear if you are asking about how to use Facebook API to implement sign-in (I assume they use some version of OAuth), or if you have a problem translating the flow into code.

Answer (score 0):

I had written one with Java and Spring, might be it will help you. Here is the link for the same : [Facebook Graph API implementation](http://aggarwalarpit.blogspot.in/2014/08/spring-social-integration-with-facebook.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [securesocial](http://securesocial.ws/) or [play-silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette).

Personally I only have experience with securesocial, together with Play 2.2. The master branch (upcoming Securesocial 3.0 release) supports Play 2.3, though you will probably need to browse the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/securesocial) to find the necessary information to set it up.